# linkedin api 400 bad request

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, linkedin-api, laravel-socialite

I am using `socialite`. And trying to integrate `linkedin`. It is OK when a user ALLOW the request. But, I get the following error when a user **cancel** the request.

[image]

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the steps here: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2.

Look at `Step 3 — Exchange Authorization Code for an Access Token`

> The final step towards obtaining an Access Token is for your application to ask for one using the Authorization Code it just acquired.  This is done by making the following "x-www-form-urlencoded" HTTP POST request.